# How do I work with several user controls?

Tags: user-controls

In Visual Studio, I have built an ASP.NET user control which constitutes an image button. The image file for it is now 1.jpg. Now, I have several such controls, and I'd like, by clicking a (regular) button in the main frame, to turn all their images into 2.jpg. How can I do this (in c#)?
I have tried to do this as follows:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType() == "typeof(...)")
    {
        ((...)c).ImageUrl = "2.jpg";
    }
}
```

What do I have to write instead of an ellipsis? (I'd like to know if it is possible to do this in the aforementioned way.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I control multiple user controls with one button in Windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27530344/how-do-i-control-multiple-user-controls-with-one-button-in-windows-form)

Comment: No. I'd like to know if it is possible to do things in the way I try to do them.